24.04 Laptop lid close action on battery
The org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power.lid-close-battery-action or lid-close-ac-action does not enact the non-default 'hibernate' setting even though systemctl hibernate works on this machine.
How to best troubleshoot this?
This is what the Journal reports when closing the lid
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad systemd-logind[1000]: Lid closed.
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad gnome-shell[2786]: g_hash_table_steal_extended: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad systemd-logind[1000]: Suspending...
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad dbus-daemon[972]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.14' (uid=0 pid=1032 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon" label="unconfined")
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad NetworkManager[1032]: <info>  [1735174191.1021] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad NetworkManager[1032]: <info>  [1735174191.1022] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad NetworkManager[1032]: <info>  [1735174191.1027] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad NetworkManager[1032]: <info>  [1735174191.1030] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad systemd[1]: Starting NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad dbus-daemon[972]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad systemd[1]: Started NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad gnome-shell[2786]: MESA-LOADER: failed to open simpledrm: /usr/lib/dri/simpledrm_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad kernel: wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from d4:01:c3:6b:20:42 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad gnome-shell[2786]: Failed to initialize accelerated iGPU/dGPU framebuffer sharing: Not hardware accelerated
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad gnome-shell[2786]: Created gbm renderer for '/dev/dri/card0'
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad wpa_supplicant[1036]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=d4:01:c3:6b:20:42 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad wpa_supplicant[1036]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad NetworkManager[1032]: <info>  [1735174191.2590] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad NetworkManager[1032]: <info>  [1735174191.2593] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad wpa_supplicant[1036]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-9999 noise=9999 txrate=0
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad NetworkManager[1032]: <info>  [1735174191.2635] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): canceled DHCP transaction
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad NetworkManager[1032]: <info>  [1735174191.2635] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad avahi-daemon[969]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::daa4:1411:4351:5fdd on wlp0s20f3.
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad NetworkManager[1032]: <info>  [1735174191.2636] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): state changed no lease
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad avahi-daemon[969]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp0s20f3.IPv6 with address fe80::daa4:1411:4351:5fdd.
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad avahi-daemon[969]: Interface wlp0s20f3.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad avahi-daemon[969]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.44.23 on wlp0s20f3.
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad avahi-daemon[969]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp0s20f3.IPv4 with address 192.168.44.23.
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad avahi-daemon[969]: Interface wlp0s20f3.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad systemd-resolved[916]: wlp0s20f3: Bus client set default route setting: no
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad systemd-resolved[916]: wlp0s20f3: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad NetworkManager[1032]: <info>  [1735174191.3009] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad wpa_supplicant[1036]: p2p-dev-wlp0s20: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad wpa_supplicant[1036]: p2p-dev-wlp0s20: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad wpa_supplicant[1036]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp0s20 disabled_11b_rates=0
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad gnome-shell[2786]: Source ID 1126 was not found when attempting to remove it
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad xdg-desktop-por[3537]: Monitor 'Built-in display' has no configuration which is-current!
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad wpa_supplicant[1036]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad wpa_supplicant[1036]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad wpa_supplicant[1036]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp0s20f3 disabled_11b_rates=0
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad rtkit-daemon[1637]: Successfully made thread 2814 of process 2786 owned by '1000' high priority at nice level 0.
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad rtkit-daemon[1637]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad update-notifier[3868]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad update-notifier[3868]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad rtkit-daemon[1637]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad rtkit-daemon[1637]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad rtkit-daemon[1637]: Successfully made thread 2814 of process 2786 owned by '1000' RT at priority 20.
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad rtkit-daemon[1637]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Dec 25 16:49:51 j-tpad kernel: simple-framebuffer simple-framebuffer.0: swiotlb buffer is full (sz: 2097152 bytes), total 32768 (slots), used 0 (slots)
Dec 25 16:49:52 j-tpad systemd[1]: Reached target sleep.target - Sleep.
Dec 25 16:49:52 j-tpad systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend...
Dec 25 16:49:52 j-tpad rtkit-daemon[1637]: Successfully made thread 2814 of process 2786 owned by '1000' high priority at nice level 0.
Dec 25 16:49:52 j-tpad rtkit-daemon[1637]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Dec 25 16:49:52 j-tpad rtkit-daemon[1637]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Dec 25 16:49:52 j-tpad rtkit-daemon[1637]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Dec 25 16:49:52 j-tpad systemd-sleep[4231]: Performing sleep operation 'suspend'...
Dec 25 16:49:52 j-tpad kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Dec 25 16:49:52 j-tpad rtkit-daemon[1637]: Successfully made thread 2814 of process 2786 owned by '1000' RT at priority 20.
Dec 25 16:49:52 j-tpad rtkit-daemon[1637]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
Dec 25 16:49:52 j-tpad kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.007 seconds


